# Is there a way to get a JSON-Schema from a Scala Case Class hierarchy?

Tags: json, scala

I'm documenting an internal REST API written ini Scala, unfortunately we are not able to integrate Swagger, so for now we are going with an in-house solution for the doc generator.
I would like to generate a JSON-Schema to show how the response is when getting our resources. I'm just wondering if there is any shortcut to do this by taking advantage of the case classes already modeled.

Answer (score 3):

The [autoschema](https://github.com/coursera/autoschema) project is able to export JSON schema from Scala case classes. You can use it as follows:

```
case class MyType(myValue: Int)
AutoSchema.createSchema[MyType]
```

The Maven artifact seems to be no longer available but it is an SBT project available on Github so you can either copy the sources, build a Jar or add it as a dependency with SBT by putting in your `build.sbt` the following:

```
lazy val autoschemaProject =
  ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/coursera/autoschema.git"), "autoschema")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(autoschemaProject)
```

I tested this with SBT 0.13.7. Notice that autoschema has its own dependencies (mainly `play-json 2.3.2`) so you might need to change their versions to avoid version conflicts with you own project dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

As @mziccard stated, autoschema is the way to go. However, it's been a while since there has been some activity on the main repository. I took some time to fork it and update its dependencies and deprecated code (work that was done in other forks, I simply combined it). It is now published in maven central under my fork:

https://github.com/sauldhernandez/autoschema

You can use it by putting this in `build.sbt`:

`libraryDependencies += "com.sauldhernandez" %% "autoschema" % "1.0.0"`