# Scala case class to json schema

Tags: json, scala, rest

I want to generate json schema of case class in order to provide some information to other service that is going to expose my app with rest api

I've got this class:

```
case class Vendor(
                  name: String,
                  synonyms: List[String],
                  transalit: String,
                  urlPart: String)
```

How can i generate like this:

```
{
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "name":{
         "type":"string"
      },
      "synonyms":{
         "type":"array",
         "items":{
            "type":"string"
         }
      },
      "translit":{
         "type":"string"
      },
      "urlPart":{
         "type":"string"
      }
   }
}
```

i found this: https://github.com/coursera/autoschema but sbt can't find dependency.

also i found this [Is there a way to get a JSON-Schema from a Scala Case Class hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779883/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-json-schema-from-a-scala-case-class-hierarchy) and this question is very similar to mine but there is no answer..

May be i'm looking for answer that doesn't exist. May be it's better to use some other techniques

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the Maven artifact for autoschema does not exist and this is why sbt can't find the dependency.

Good news is that with sbt you can import a project from github and add it as a dependency. In your `build.sbt` add the following:

```
lazy val autoschemaProject =
  ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/coursera/autoschema.git"), "autoschema")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(autoschemaProject)
```

Notice that `root` might already be defined in your `build.sbt`, in this case only add `dependsOn(autoschemaProject)`.
I tested this with sbt 0.13.7 and I managed to use autoschema to generate a json schema from a case class.

Comment: I got this dependency error:
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:play-json_2.10:2.3.2 (/home/user256/.sbt/0.13/staging/00472dcce208f679d89f/autoschema/build.sbt#L23-27)
[warn]            +- org.coursera:autoschema_2.10:0.1
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last {https://github.com/coursera/autoschema.git}autoschema/*:update for the full output.
[error] ({https://github.com/coursera/autoschema.git}autoschema/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.10;2.3.2: not found

Comment: Weird, I don't get that error. Maybe have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157135/play-2-2-2-com-typesafe-playplay-2-102-2-2-not-found-on-heroku) stackoverflow question. Notice that you might have to add the resolver to the autoschema build.sbt: (`/home/user256/.sbt/0.13/staging/00472dcce208f679d89f/autoschema/build.sbt`).

Comment: In my project i also use play-json: "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.4.0". I suppose sbt gets confused when i make dependsOn project that use lower version of play-json library. I'll try to add resolver to auto schema/build.sbt later and let you know. Thanks

Comment: You will have to set the same version for both projects otherwise you are going to have conflicts. However, this version discrepancy should not affect dependency resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The project has been forked:
`https://github.com/sauldhernandez/autoschema`

Now, you can get the artifact by adding this dependency to your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.sauldhernandez" %% "autoschema" % "1.0.4"
```